# How do I run a mock of a C function in one module, but run the actual implementation in another module while using link time substitution?

Tags: c, unit-testing, mocking, linker, cpputest

I have a scenario where my coworker is writing functions that I wish to use in my module. He wrote the unit tests for his module, and I am writing the unit tests for mine. Naturally I would like to mock his functions for my test.

The production code is written in C and compiled as a library separately from the Unit test code. At link time, we are overwriting the object code of the production for the Mock version. However this overwrites **ALL** calls to that particular function instead of just in my unit tests.

Here is an example.

Using CPPUTEST, I have `MockSupport_c.h` at my disposal. So I write up a mock for his function. Ex

real function:

```
int read_bytes(int count)
{
    // for loop read the bytes
    return success;
}
```

I call the above with my function that I want to test

```
int read()
{
    return read_bytes(256);
}
```

The test module looks something like the following:

```
// create the mock
int read_bytes(int count)
{
    mock_c()->actualCall("read_bytes");
    return 1;
}

// test the code
TEST(group, test_name)
{
    mock_c()->expectOneCall("read_bytes");
    read();
    mock_c()->checkExpectations();
}
```

When the unit test is compiled, the linker will replace the production code implementation with the mocked version; but it will do it for all calls to that function. So my coworkers unit tests now call mocks, when it should be testing his actual calls.

How do I get the mocks to only apply during my tests, and not overwrite my coworkers calls?

Or am I just way off base with how all of this works?

Comment: How do you compile and link? Why can't you link each test with the appropriate real or mock modules?

Comment: After compilation, the result is 1 single executable that will exercise all tests. With the production code being compiled as a library, and the mocks either in their own library or in the main execution; the linker (by design) will link the call to the first function that matches said call. So if I put the mocks first on the command line, the linker will fill **all** calls to that mock, then load the production library and fill in the rest... and if I put the production library first on the command line, then the linker will link all function calls to the real code and non to the mocks.

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio vc++ compiler tool chain. In my reading, I have discovered no way to specify to the linker which functions get switched out and which functions dont. If there is a way to do that, then I would really like to know. I am sure that would solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, wow. Is this a requirement of your development process, or of CppUTest? I'm really sure that the unit testing framework provides some ideas how to handle this. -- However, if you _must_ create a single executable, you might consider to use some preprocessor magic to let the compiler differentiate the use cases (real/mock).

Comment: There are no set requirements for how the unit-testing frame work is implemented, only that we do it. So I have some flexibility. I have chosen to do link-time substitution because I find it to be the cleanest solution for switching out functions without modifying the production code base. Littering our code with `#ifdef` is not something that the team is fond of.

Having multiple executables is an acceptable solution, so long as their management is an easy, automated, solution. This is something I have not thoroughly looked into; so more information is welcome.

Comment: I never used CppUTest, so my experience is mainly limited to a (closed-source) in-house framework for C, which was derived from MinUnit, and GoogleTest. However, current frameworks should work in similar manners. -- I always found it the most simple solution to create an executable for each test suite (or even test case), and have as many executables as seen fit. With a Makefile this leads to quick development cycles, as only changed (that is: worked-on) tests will be compiled, linked, and run. Use Make variables to list all executables, and so on.

Comment: okay, it certainly seems like that might be my best solution. 

I also found the same question being asked over on the TDD stackexchange and it seems that your recommendation is the same as theirs. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163360/test-driven-development-with-plain-c-manage-multiple-modules

I will play around with it and report back. Thank you.